# Bugzilla cannot connect to an SMTP server

Tags: bugzilla

In a fresh Bugzilla installation (5.0.3), on a Scientific Linux 6 server I can't set the mail parameters due to this error:

`The new value for smtpserver is invalid: Cannot connect to mail.smpt.server`

Despite the fact that SMTP settings are correct. The SMTP server for the company is fully functional, on that server I downloaded thunderbird and was able to log in to my account smoothly without any problem which should mean the server has no problem with SMTP at all.

I'm still searching with no clear hind what the cause could be. Any help is really appreciated!

Update: In the old installation I can set these values and I can submit a bug but the email is not sent. [This](http://johnpwood.net/2008/04/01/bugzilla-and-smtp-authentication/) article says that bugzilla does not support SMTP with authentication (Not sure if true or not).

Update: I installed the necessary modules [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=466419#c1) and again no luck.

Update: On the old installation (4.something), we managed to setup an email account without authentication. This Bugzilla can now send email and it should work smoothly.

Update: I found this useful [article](http://johnpwood.net/2008/04/01/bugzilla-and-smtp-authentication/) which applies a custom send mail script but the error message could not tell me where the error is.

Comment: Update: On the old installation (4.something), we managed to setup an email account without authentication. This Bugzilla can now send email and it should work smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `mail.smpt.server` is a hostname that resolves internally, you must have a typo: isn't this `mail.smtp.server` instead?

Whatever the hostname you have configured, you can check with the following command that it resolves properly:

```
getent hosts mail.smpt.server
(or mail.smtp.server most probably)
```

You can then try to connect to this server on port 25:

```
$ telnet mail.smtp.server 25 <<< QUIT
Trying 111.222.333.444...
Connected to mail.smtp.server.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

(the "Connected..." line means everything should work)

Comment: that address is just a dummy address to show the message. But yeah the address resolves perfectly.

Comment: @3bdalla Did you try the `telnet` part with the user that runs Bugzilla?

Comment: What do you mean with the user that runs bugzilla?

Comment: @3bdalla I mean the user that does the connect to the SMTP server. It may be the user that runs your web server.

Comment: I did what you posted and it works. Not sure how to specify the user.

Comment: become the user (`sudo su www-data`) and run the *telnet* session.

Comment: @umläute That's right. But your daemon user `www-data` (which may be called `apache`, `httpd`, etc. on platforms others than Debian/Ubuntu) has probably no valid shell. You must use `su -l -s /bin/bash www-data` instead.